# How to merge a collection field into another collection field without duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am getting results from a aggregate query on a collection called "fileprocessingrequest". I trying to merge a field AssetIDArray(array) from the result of "fileprocessingrequest" collection to another collection called "subscriber" which consists of a field dvr_id(Array). It should not allow duplicate ID's to merge

I am trying to figure out how to merge the AssetID array into dvr_id array without duplication of records.

Below is the result of aggregate on fileprocessingrequest collection

```
[{"AssetIDArray":["SID_BIGBANG_2ACF","SID_BIGBANG_2ACD","SID_BIGBANG_2ACC","SID_BIGBANG_2ACB"],"count":7}]
```

The subscriber collection result looks like this

```
[{"_id":"5cca2a6a1055de2ff407d4c3","dvr_id":["SID_BIGBANG_2ACF","SID_BIGBANG_2ACD"]}]
```

I expect the array in "fileprocessingrequest" collection to merge with the array in "subscriber" collection without duplication. I am not able to figure out how I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const setId = new Set([...AssetIDArray, ...dvr_id]);
const uniqArr = Array.from(_set);
```